# how to check datetime in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, date, datetime, isodate

```
posts = [{"content":"content1",
          "created":"2013-12-27T14: 15: 27.747Z"},
         {"content":"content2",
          "created":"2013-12-27T14: 15: 02.956Z"}]
```

How to check `posts[0]` and `posts[1]` was created in the same day or not with Angularjs?

Comment: What is that date format?

Comment: In addition to the answer by Ilan Frumer, you may want to check [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for ultimate flexibility when dealing with dates/times in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular doesn't really have a built in way to compare dates, but it can be done in conjunction with angular.

http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/LxTGd/1/

This will compare if the **day, month, and year** are the same, determining if the 2 dates are on the same day (time is irrelevant).

```
$scope.sameDay = function(date1,date2){
    return date1.substring(0,10) === date2.substring(0,10);
}
```

This functionality would ideally be made into some sort of directive.  But this is just a basic example, a directive example can be made if required.

Comment: If you do it with substring why not just : `date1.substring(0,10) === date2.substring(0,10)` ?

Comment: True, lol, I was just thinking in dates >.<  Updated and +1 for you

Answer (score 0):

javascript cannot parse ISODATE which contain spaces:

```
post[0].created.replace(/\s/g,'')
```

That's how you compare dates:

```
(new Date(post[0].created).toDateString) === (new Date(post[1].created).toDateString)
```

Comment: @IIan Frumer TypeError: Object #<post[0]> has no method 'replace'

Comment: replace is a string method and your post[0] is an object.